# Akeneo import failing, unable to read or upload files?

Tags: akeneo

I've been trying to get Akeneo CE up an running to give it a try. It's pretty much all functioning except I can't use the import feature. If I use the upload file box on the frontend I just get "File not found at path..." error. If I upload the file manually and specify path, I just get "Unable to read the file..." error.

Installed on WHM cPanel server.

I'm using the minimal DB to start from scratch.

I've checked all permissions and they seem right.

I can export fine.

I enabled the exec function as indicated by the sys reqs regarding import/export.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: Long time ago, that was version 3.0. I ended up having to use a full path when configuring the files upload directory in one of the (.yml I think) config files. Using a relative path just would not work even using the project root alias. So uploading the file basically just failed without error then the error came trying to read the nonexistent file. 

They changed how this works in 4.0+  as well as the dir structure though. It now looks in installdir/srv/pim/tmp for uploads and puts them there as well (it can probbaly be changed, but it worked OOTB for me.

Comment: Due to hosting limitations, we're stuck with 3.2 for now. This actually helps me a lot. Thanks!